# pop up box alignment is different in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a pop up which comes when password text box is focused.
The alignment of the box is as I want in Chrome but it displays differently in Firefox.

Can someone help with this? TIA

Here's my code

```
<tr >
    <td> Password: </td>
    <td><input type = "password" name = "pass" id = "pass" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <div id = "req">
        <ul>
            <li id = "uppercase" class = "invalid">1 upper case letter</li>
            <li id = "lowercase" class = "invalid">1 lower case letter</li>
            <li id = "number" class = "invalid">1 number</li>
            <li id = "char" class = "invalid">8 or more characters</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
#req {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:460px;
    right:419px;
    width:210px;
    background:#fefefe;
    font-size:.875em;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 3px #ccc;
    border:3px solid black;
    z-index : 100;
}

#req::before {
    content: "\25C0";
    position:absolute;
    top : 45px;
    left : -11px;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:14px;
    text-shadow:none;
    display:block;
}

#req{
    display : none;
}
```

Here's my Javascript Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[id=pass]').keyup(function() {
        //code 
    }).focus(function() {
        $('#req').show();
    }).blur(function() {
        $('#req').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: they look the same to me. the `bottom` and `right` values don't work as-is with this code, so I changed it to `top: 0; left: 0;` so the popup would appear. what's the difference you're trying to resolve? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmwYqb